# Find element at HTML string

Tags: jquery, dom

Let's suppose I have

```
var testHTML = "<div id='demo_div'></div>";
```

I want to get above **div** as JQuery object to manipulate with it. I try to find it with:

```
 var found = $(testHTML).find("#demo_div");
```

and with:

```
 var found = $(testHTML).find("div");
```

Both without luck. I have empty *found* variable. What am I do wrong?

**P.S.** Yes I know I can have direct access to my **div** with

```
$("#demo_div")
```

but I can't do it in my case - I need to get it from plain HTML that will be assigned to some variable just like in my example with *testHTML* var.

**UPDATE:** 
Even if I have not root **div** element like here:

```
var testHTML = "<html><div id='demo_div'></div></html>";
```

I can't use *find* for navigating *div* element.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The problem is that your `div` is the root element in the collection, so you need to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) (which only looks at descendant elements):

```
var found = $(testHTML).filter("#demo_div");
```

I'm assuming your actual HTML string is more complex than the one in the question, otherwise you don't need to do anything other than `$(testHTML)` and you will have a jQuery object containing that single element.

Comment: Yes I have more complex HTML and my div is not the root of it. But _find_ is not work there!

Comment: @MichaelZ - Then your problem is most likely elsewhere. If the element you are looking for is at the root of the collection, use `.filter()`, if it's not, use `.find()`. See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/CWnvu/1/).

Comment: @MichaelZ - jQuery strips out the `<html>` element, so your `div` is actually the root.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`.search()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp) function of the javascript itself.

```
testHTML.search('demo_div')>-1
```