# jquery increase with of last th

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tableheader

How to increase width of last th in a string? I am trying to make it current width + 20px;

[here is my code in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sBbcE/)

```
var header="<th id="tblHeader_1" style="width: 80px;"><span>Id</span></th>
<th class="headerSortDown" id="tblHeader_2" style="width: 300px;"><span>Title</span></th>
<th class="headerSortDown" id="tblHeader_3" style="width: 300px;"><span>Adress</span></th>";


//Increase last th width
header.find(th:last).css('width',currentwidth+20+'px');    
alert(header);
```

Comment: You can't do jQuery actions on HTML inside a variable. It only works when the HTML is in the DOM.

Comment: try use replace , `header.repalce('id="tblHeader_1" style="width: 80px;"','id="tblHeader_1" style="width: '+currentwidth+20+'px;"');`

Comment: @GerbenJacobs True, but you can convert HTML string to a jQuery object - seee Felix's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert your `header` to jQuery object using `$` in order to use jQuery method here:

```
$(header).find('th:last').css('width',currentwidth+20+'px');
```

Also, you need to use `' '` to wrap your string instead of `" "`:

```
var header='<th id="tblHeader_1" style="width: 80px;"><span>Id</span></th><th class="headerSortDown" id="tblHeader_2" style="width: 300px;"><span>Title</span></th><th class="headerSortDown" id="tblHeader_3" style="width: 300px;"><span>Adress</span></th>';
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to create a jQuery object from your HTML string, then you need to actually get the current width of the `th` before increasing it:

```
th = $(header).find('th:last');
th.css('width', (th.width() + 20) + 'px');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var header = $('<th id="tblHeader_1" style="width: 80px;"><span>Id</span></th><th class="headerSortDown" id="tblHeader_2" style="width: 300px;"><span>Title</span></th><th class="headerSortDown" id="tblHeader_3" style="width: 300px;"><span>Adress</span></th>');
$(header[header.length-1]).css({width:"+=20"});
alert(header);
```

demo here http://jsfiddle.net/sBbcE/2/

Answer (score 1):

[LIVE DEMO filter()](http://jsfiddle.net/sBbcE/7/)

Problem here JQuery find() doesn't works well with HTML String . First we need into inject into DOM then it will work fine.

It works fine with `filter()` method better explanation here [Find element at HTML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413399/find-element-at-html-string)

```
var header='<th id="tblHeader_1" style="width:80px;"><span>Id</span></th><th class="headerSortDown" id="tblHeader_2" style="width: 100px;"><span>Title</span></th><th class="headerSortDown" id="tblHeader_3" style="width:100px;"><span>Adress</span></th>';

var $header =  $(header);

var th = $header.filter("th:last");

th.css('width',th.width() + 50 + 'px');

$header.appendTo('#main');
```

Another way with `find()` method.

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sBbcE/5/)

```
var header='<th id="tblHeader_1" style="width:80px;"><span>Id</span></th><th class="headerSortDown" id="tblHeader_2" style="width: 100px;"><span>Title</span></th><th class="headerSortDown" id="tblHeader_3" style="width:100px;"><span>Adress</span></th>';

var currentwidth = 100;

$('#main').append(header).find('th:last').css('background-color','red');//For Testing pu

//Increase last th width
$('#main').find('th:last').css('width',currentwidth + 50 + 'px');
```

[Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159426/using-jquery-to-search-a-string-of-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159426/using-jquery-to-search-a-string-of-html)