# get the string enclosed in a tag in a string Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, tags

I am trying to get data enclosed between tags in  a string. I get a string in such format and I need to parse it to get only whats enclosed in tags.

```
var s = "Something something <details>Required data</details>";
```

I want to get the data that is enclosed between the `<details>` tag

I tried

```
alert($('s').find('details').text());
```

But its just blank output.
Regular expressions would help but it seems to me that there maybe is a better way.

I would welcome any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo** 1.8.2 and above: http://jsfiddle.net/SSL2q/

**Demo** 1.7.2 and below : http://jsfiddle.net/FGpSP/

API:

- `parseHTML` - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

old replies: [Find element at HTML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413399/find-element-at-html-string) or [How to get an HTML element from a string with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754092/how-to-get-an-html-element-from-a-string-with-jquery) worth a read.

Hope rest fits your needs `:)`

**Code**

```
var s = "something sometihng <details> I want this </details>";

alert("abc");
alert($(s).filter('details').text());
```

**Code**

```
var s = "something sometihng <details> I want this </details>";

alert("abc");
alert($($.parseHTML(s)).filter('details').text());
```

Answer (score 4):

> If a string is passed as the parameter to $(), jQuery examines the
>   string to see if it looks like HTML (i.e., it starts with ).
>   If not, the string is interpreted as a selector expression, as
>   explained above.

It seems that jQuery is confused at your html string and treats it as a selector. When you want to explicitely parse html, you may need to use `$.parseHTML`.

```
var s = "Something something <details>Required data</details>",
    $s = $($.parseHTML(s)),
    text = $s.filter('details').text();

console.log(text); //Required data
```

You could also do something like:

```
$('<div>').html(s).find('details').text();
```

Comment: Note : $.parseHTML() needs jquery 1.8 +

Comment: Nice job, actually i prefer the alternative

Comment: Thanks plaix .. :D .. I like both the answers posted to my question and both of them work. Unfortunately I can only pick one as correct.. I am really thankful for your inputs :D ..