# Why does $.get keep coming up as an empty alert?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to get the `href` of `<span id="username">` from another page on my website.

The jQuery:

```
var fetchedInfo;
$.get("./profile", function(res) {
   fetchedInfo = $(res).find("span#username").attr("href");
   alert(fetchedInfo);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="linkdiv">
    <span class="profile" id="username">
        <a href="https://example.com">text</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Every answer I've tried from StackOverflow has resulted in a blank Alert. I'm not sure if there's something way deeper going on from my end of things or if it's still (hopefully) a fixable code issue...

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `span` does not have a `href` attribute, but the `a` tag inside it has. You need to include the `a` tag in the `find(...)`:

```
var fetchedInfo;
$.get("./profile", function(res) {
   fetchedInfo = $(res).find("span#username a").attr("href");
   alert(fetchedInfo);
});
```

Also, I would recommend you to test your stuff with `console.log(...)` like so to see what each step really does. That way you know which step fails.

```
var fetchedInfo;
$.get("./profile", function(res) {
   console.log($(res));
   console.log($(res).find("span#username a"));
   console.log($(res).find("span#username a").attr("href"));
   fetchedInfo = $(res).find("span#username a").attr("href");
   alert(fetchedInfo);
});
```

Comment: Even though this is probably the technical answer it actually comes up `Undefined` now. Not sure why it changed from blank to undefined. . It's probably something wrong with the way I did the other code at this point. if you have ideas please let me know. I've been spending a while on this.

Comment: do some debugging and if you have more info, I can maybe help you. What does `console.log(res)` print? and `console.log($(res))`? and and `console.log($(res).find("span#username a"))`? @m0a

Comment: Thank you . `console.log($(res))` returned undefined. `console.log(res)` did return the correct info. Then `fetchedInfo = ((res).find("span#username a").attr("href"));` returns a new error- "res.find is not a function". So this is really close!

Comment: what does `console.log(res)` print? the html text?

Comment: OK, after observing the actual HTML that got printed, I see what's happening but don't get why or how to deal with it. The HTML is not pulling the particular div that I'm trying to pull data from, probably because I create that page's div via JS-- it's not a static part of the HTML.

Comment: maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413399/find-element-at-html-string @m0a